# PayPal sandbox for testing - is it safe?

Tags: api, security, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've been working with PayPal's Adaptive Payments API for a while and i'm ready to begin testing of my website.

My plan is to create a bunch of PayPal sandbox accounts and give them to family and friends to use on my site.

However, I've noticed that when I log in to a sandbox account (at sandbox.paypal.com), it says 'Logged in as real-account@example.com' where real-account@example.com is my actual PayPal account.

Does logging in to the fake sandbox accounts give the testers access to my real PayPal account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  Your real PayPal email address shows up at the top of the page because that's what you used to sign into https://developer.paypal.com, and there's a cookie on your computer telling the Sandbox that you signed in with that email address.  It won't show up for other users.

Comment: thanks for your quick response! Is my plan the recommended way for testing PayPal integration (specifically giving sandbox credentials to a bunch of people)?

Comment: It might be advisable to have them go to https://developer.paypal.com and create their own sandbox account.  It's possible that they might receive a "this sandbox account is not available" message when signing into one of your accounts.

Comment: If in doubt, launch an incognito window and try to check out using one of the sandbox accounts you created.  If it doesn't work, then chances are it won't work for your users either.

Comment: I assume you mean getting my testers to log in to the dev site from their real PayPal accounts and set up sandbox accounts? Would they be able to use my site from these? I also use the getVerifiedStatus operation, would this be usable in this scenario? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes and yes.  There is some level of validation that happens on sandbox accounts, when you log into them, to make sure that they belong to the developer.paypal.com account that the user is signed into.  They can still make payments to any other sandbox account, and GetVerifiedStatus isn't affected.

Comment: It seems to be working from incognito so I'll stick with the easy approach!